# In marionette view, redirect to another route when login success, given appRouter is not available in view function

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am using browserify to test water Marionette. I succeed to this point:

```
// Here is the singup function in LoginView which extends from Marionette.Layout.View


signin: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#input-email').val();
    var password = $('#input-password').val();
    var userAuth = new UserAuthenticateModel({
        email: email,
        password: password
    });
    if(userAuth.isValid()) {
        // signin
        userAuth.save(null, {
            success: function (model, resp, options) {


                if(resp.code === 200) {
                    alert('login is good');
                    // I need to redirect to 'localhost:3333/app' route
                    // how should I do it? given appRouter, event/trigger is not available.
                    window.location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com'; // It looks not a good solution
                    return;
                } 

                if(resp.code === 406) {
                    // password doesn't match
                    alert('code 406');
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('login http request is not successful');
            }
        });
    } else {
        // show error message
    }
}
```

My question is, when login success, how should I redirect to another route? Given I am using Browserify to load module, there is no myAppRouter object available in global scope. 
I guess there are 2 options, but I don't know how to implement them.

1) call myAppRouter (extends from Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter), but it is not available in view module, what shall I do? require it and new one? then it will be in a circular dependency.

2) use some kind event/trigger to send a route change msg to myAppRouter, but still I don't know how to do it.

3) other best practice to handle route change in view function when use login success, which I also don't know about. I am using browserify, please also take this into consideration.

Can somebody help me by provide some breif description and sample code? I prefer not in coffee script, since I can't understand it yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is pretty close to your other question I just answered :). I'm not super familiar with browserify but can you take a look at my solution and see if that works for you as far as the listening to the App.vent message that gets triggered from the view/controller? If not let me know and I can dig a little more into browserify to see if I can figure out a better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks, Tom! I'll look into it~